# node.js hmac.digest() output seems wrong

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement a Facebook library with node.js, and the request signing isn't working. I have the PHP example [seen here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) translated into node. I'm trying it out with the example given there, where the secret is the string "secret". My code looks like this:

```
var signedRequest = request.signed_request.split('.');

var sig = b64url.decode(signedRequest[0]);

var expected = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'secret').update(signedRequest[1]).digest();

console.log(sig == expected); // false
```

I can't `console.log` the decoded strings themselves, because they have special characters that cause the console to clear (if you have a suggestion to get around that please let me know) but I can output the b64url encodings of them.

The expected encoded sig, as you can see on the FB documentation, is

```
vlXgu64BQGFSQrY0ZcJBZASMvYvTHu9GQ0YM9rjPSso
```

My `expected` value, when encoded, is

```
wr5Vw6DCu8KuAUBhUkLCtjRlw4JBZATCjMK9wovDkx7Dr0ZDRgzDtsK4w49Kw4o
```

So why do I think it's `digest` that's wrong? Maybe the error is on my side? Well, if I execute the exact example in PHP given in the documentation, the correct result comes out. But if I change the `hash_hmac` call so the last parameter is false, outputting hex, I get

```
YmU1NWUwYmJhZTAxNDA2MTUyNDJiNjM0NjVjMjQxNjQwNDhjYmQ4YmQzMWVlZjQ2NDM0NjBjZjZiOGNmNGFjYQ==
```

Now, if I go back to my javascript code, and change my hmac code to `.digest("hex")` instead of the default `"binary"` and log the base64 encoding of the result, I get... surprise!

```
YmU1NWUwYmJhZTAxNDA2MTUyNDJiNjM0NjVjMjQxNjQwNDhjYmQ4YmQzMWVlZjQ2NDM0NjBjZjZiOGNmNGFjYQ
```

Same, except the == signs are missing off the end, but I think that's a console thing. I can't imagine that being the issue, without them it's not even a valid base64 string length.

So, how come the digest method outputs the correct result when using hex, but the wrong answer when using binary? Is the binary not quite the same as the "raw" output of the PHP equivalent? And if that's the case what is the correct way to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Tesserex's partner.  I believe the answer may have been combination of both Tesserex's self posted answer and Juicy Scripter's answer.  We were still using Node ver. 0.4.7.  The bug Tesserex mentioned can be found here: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/324. I'm not entirely certain that this bug affected us, but it seems a good possibility.  We updated Node to ver 0.6.5 and applied Juicy Scripter's solution and everything is now working.  Thank you.

As a note about the suggestion of using existing libraries.  Most of the existing libraries require express, this is something we are trying to avoid do to some of the specifics of our application.  Also the existing libraries tend to assume that your using node.js like a web server and answering a single users request at a time.  We are using persistent connections with websockets and our facebook client will be handling session data for multiple users simultaneously.  Eventually I hope to make our Facebook client open source for use with applications like ours.

Comment: Just checked, and the code I've provided works perfectly with [v0.4.7](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/c85455a954411b38232e79752d4abb61bb75031b)...

Answer (score 1):

We have discovered that this was indeed a bug in the crypto lib, and was a known issue logged on github. We will have to upgrade and get the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no problem with `digest`, the results of `b64url.decode` are in `utf8` encoding by default (which can be specified by second parameter) if you use:

```
var sig = b64url.decode(signedRequest[0], 'binary');
var expected = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'secret').update(signedRequest[1]).digest();
// sig === expected
```

signature and result of digest will be the same.

You may also check this by turning `digest` results into `utf8` encoded string:

```
var sig = b64url.decode(signedRequest[0]);
var expected = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'secret').update(signedRequest[1]).digest();
var expected_buffer = new Buffer(expected_sig.digest(), 'binary');
// sig === expected_buffer.toString()
```

---

Also you may consider using existing libraries to do that kind of work (and probably more), to name a few:

- [facebook-wrapper](https://github.com/vladbagrin/facebook-wrapper)
- [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth)